# Login functionality from external API in React with Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth-2.0, jwt, passport.js

I’m having trouble figuring out how to get Node.js backend tokens into React.js frontend local storage. To login a user will use their credentials though an external websites API using the Oauth2 flow, this will be the only way to login into the application.

Currently, the user clicks a button which opens a new window in the authorization URL where the user will grant privilege. Once granted, the user is redirected to the backend endpoint which goes through passport.js and gets the required access and refresh tokens sent from the external API. This is then stored in a session on the backend database. What I want, instead, is to not store a session on a database but instead implement JWT and store the user’s data in local storage. With the current flow, its just not possible to do this and I haven’t found the right documentation to work it out.

There are many websites that implement it the exact way I want but tracking down the way they do it has appeared to be a challenge in on itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of using passport.js, which was causing a plethora of issues, I decided to implement the Oauth2 flow myself. Instead of doing ALL the work in the backend, I broke the flow into different parts.

Originally, I sent the user to the backend where they would recieve an authorization token there. This turned out to be troublesome, instead, request an authorization code on the front end. For example, send the user to the Auth path and redirect the user back the the front end once privileges have been granted. Wait at the frontend callback for a code, once obtained, send a post request to the backend with that code and any other data in the body.

When obtained at the backend, trade that code for the access token and respond to the post requst with the neccassary token and any other data that needs to be sent back e.g. profile name, picture, date of birth. You can the implementn the JWT flow and no database is required to store any session or tokens, all can be stored client side securely.